# Reference initialization with constructor

Tags: c++, constructor, reference, initialization, declaration

```
const T   a {}; // constant of type T
const T&  b {}; // ???
      T   c {}; // variable of type T
      T&  d {}; // error
```

What is the difference between `a` and `b`?
`b` is a reference but I don't assign a object to it: in that instruction I initialize it by T constructor.
The address of `b` is between the addresses of a and c, so it seems the `b` and `a` have no differences.

And if I can declare and initialize `b` why `d` gives compilation error?

I talked about a generic type T. I tested the code above either for primitive types and classes and the results are the same.

Comment: Have you tried to compile the code? What did you notice?

Comment: `a` and `b` are exactly the same except for the result of `decltype(x)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In these declarations

```
const T   a {}; // constant of type T
const T&  b {};
```

there is created constant object `a` that is default initialized and constant reference `b` to temporary object that is default initialized.

The compiler issues an error for this declaration of a reference

```
T&  d {}; // error
```

because there is declared a non-constant reference to a temporary object.

You could declare an rvalue reference the following way

T&&  d {};

Here is a demonstrative program

```
#include <iostream>

int main() 
{
    const int &ri {};

    std::cout << "ri = " << ri << '\n';

    int && rri {};

    std::cout << "rri = " << rri << '\n';

    return 0;
}
```

The program output is

```
ri = 0
rri = 0
```

Comment: So I guess that in `b` the lifetime of the temporary object is extended and then to "correct" `d` I would have to use an rvalue reference:
```T&&  d {};```
Right?

Comment: @DPD- The lifetime of the both temporary objects is as long as the lifetime of references thet refer these temporary objects.